# Hyperledger Fabric 2.3 and Caliper V0.5 Issue

Tags: hyperledger-caliper

`I am not able to test my fabric 2.3 test network by using Caliper V0.5

Hi I am using fabric 2.3 test-network and testing performance with Caliper v0.5. I am also getting similar errors like.

No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
peer=undefined, status=grpc, message=Peer endorsements do not match

Failed to submitTransaction, No valid response from peers

All fabric components are UP and running. Is there any issue with my configuration files. I am sharing my benchmark and network configuration. Please see and suggest the solution.'

**My Caliper Benchmark Configuration is as follows:**

test:
name: basic-contract-benchmark
description: test benchmark
workers:
number: 2
rounds:
- label: readAsset
description: Read asset benchmark
txDuration: 30
rateControl:
type: fixed-load
opts:
#tps: 25
transactionLoad: 2
workload:
module: workload/readAsset.js
arguments:
assets: 10
contractId: basic
**My Caliper Network Configuration is as follows:**
name: Calier test
version: "2.0.0"

caliper:
blockchain: fabric

channels:

- channelName: channel1
  contracts:

  - id: basic

organizations:

- mspid: Org1MSP
  identities:
  certificates:

  - name: 'User1'
    clientPrivateKey:
    path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/663cf2aa45619b05d8c8200020f90d7931dcc08f15b8b152a16c6ea7e344e8d5_sk'
    clientSignedCert:
    path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem'
    connectionProfile:
    path: '../fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.yaml'
    discover: true

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Peer endorsements do not match` implies that a transaction proposal was submitted and to satisfy the endorsement policy it was sent to more than 1 peer. Responses from all the peers were received and they did not match (they should be identical). This message isn't a caliper message but a fabric message and thus is not a problem with caliper, but more likely the chaincode you are testing is not deterministic. I would suggest reviewing the hyperledger fabric documentation about chaincode determinism, but examples code in chaincode that are likely to make it non-deterministic are

1. getting the current date and/or time
2. generating a random number

chaincode that does this is going to be non-deterministic is you use these values to generate keys or form part of a property (2 peers running the same code are going to generate different values)

Comment: My chaincode is working fine. I can make transactions using the CLI commands. But when I use Caliper to inject transactions, I am getting errors like "Peer endorsements do no match" or "Peers not responding", and "Failed to submitTransaction". I am using Caliper v0.5 with fabric 2.3 ( is this combination ok)

Comment: Are you monitoring the resources being used by caliper and hyperledger fabric such as cpu and memory and disk i/o ? Don't try to run caliper and hyperledger fabric on the same physical machine to ensure they aren't competing for the same resources. As for Peer endorsements do not match, if it's not a chaincode issue then its possible that 1 peer is so far behind the other in terms of block height that the endorsements do not match because the peers are looking at different values. All this along with the other messages could indicate a performance issue with the fabric network.